# Return data into input fields for update operation using inner joins

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do its a system to update data inside the database from a frontend which already fills in the inputs with the information that it finds in the database so that you will be able to see how it is right now and then input the new values.

Problem is that when I'm returning values like name,email,phone it works. But when I try to join my tables so that for city I wont have in the input field a value like 159 which its the key value for a specific city in my database.

It brakes. Printing out this error.

### SQL Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous' in ....PATH TO FILE......: PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in .....PATH TO FILE....... on line 98
```

### Broken Code

Here you have the code that I`m running in that part of the script.

```
     else {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT
  Users.id,
  Users.firstname,
  Users.lastname,
  Users.email,
  Users.age,
  Users.phone,
  Universities.univ AS university,
  Internship.internship_type AS Internship,
  Orase.oras AS city,
  Interes.interes AS interest,
  User_status.user_status AS userstatus,
  Users.filename,
  Users.account,
  Users.reg_date
FROM
  Users
INNER JOIN
  Orase ON Users.city = Orase.cheie
INNER JOIN
  Universities ON Users.university = Universities.id
INNER JOIN
  Interes ON Users.interest = Interes.cheie
INNER JOIN
  Internship ON Users.Internship_type = Internship.cheie
INNER JOIN
  User_status ON Users.user_status = User_status.id 
WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $name = $data['firstname'];
        $lastname = $data['lastname'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $age = $data['age'];
        $mobile = $data['phone'];
        $city = $data['city'];
        Database::disconnect();
    }
```

### Code that actually works

Also here is the same script working without inner joins so that my city returns a numeric value.

```
else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $name = $data['firstname'];
    $lastname = $data['lastname'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $age = $data['age'];
    $mobile = $data['phone'];
    $city = $data['city'];
    Database::disconnect();
}

?>
```

### Image with the form using working code

Image for context so that you understand why I'm trying to use inner joins for the name of the city
[image: Image for context so that you understand why I'm trying to use inner joins for the name of the city]

Comment: Replace `WHERE id = ?` for `WHERE Users.id = ?`

Comment: Pfff. You are so right. :) Can`t believe I missed that. I was just thinking that ohhh but I select Users so that WHERE id = ? should work. Thank You @sef4eg

Comment: Let's consider it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `WHERE id = ?` for `WHERE Users.id = ?`